# Get output of FOR with EOF in bash

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, scripting

I've created a bash script to temporarily help me send some files to a FTP server based on the id of the commit, i get the last commit, track the files and send as listed below.

```
#!/bin/bash

commit_hash=$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)

[[ -z "$1" ]] || commit_hash=$1

files=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit_hash)

echo -e $(git log -1 $commit_hash --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s");
printf "\n"

HOST=
USER=
PASS=

for file in $files; do
ftp -nv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd /www/example
passive
put $file
bye
EOF

done;
```

of course it isn't the best approach to do that, but i automated some things that i am currently working on.

it is possible to catch the ftp output of the heredoc and apply some filters? with pipelines for example, i only want to know if the transfer was completed successfully.

Comment: How about checking the exit status code of `ftp` with the `$?` bash variable? It may contain enough information to figure out if the request succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to catch the ftp output of the heredoc and apply some filters? with pipelines for example, i only want to know if the transfer was completed successfully.

I presume you mean you want to catch the output of the `ftp` command whose input is redirected from the heredoc; the heredoc itself does not have output in a sense that anything other than the associated command can see.

But you can redirect *the command's* output.  The thing to remember is that the heredoc begins on the next line, not immediately after the associated redirection operator.  Thus, you can add a pipeline to another command after the heredoc operator.  For example:

```
$ cat << EOF | grep flag
flag this line
not this line
or this line
flag this
last flag
EOF
```

Output:

```
flag this line
flag this
last flag
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a `for` loop for this. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

```
commit_hash=${1:-$(git log --format="%H" -n 1)}

while IFS= read -r file; do
  ftp -nv "$HOST" << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd /www/example
passive
put $file
bye
EOF
done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$commit_hash")
```